# Process for submitting Encrypted iOS apps to Appstore outside US

Tags: ios, app-store

We are using api's from ssl encrypted server in our app(https://), we have to deploy the in UK region.
Can we directly upload the app,or need to follow any special procedure.
If we took an iOS developer account from UK address, will it help in faster deployment process.

Comment: You need to meet the U.S. crypto regulations the same as a U.S. based developer because Apple is based in the U.S.

Answer (score 0):

No special procedures needed. The developer account's registered region plays no role. Just upload the app normally.

Comment: The API used for the actual HTTP connection cannot affect deployment (in terms of App Store) aspects. I suggest using the more recent NSURLSession API though, especially if security is a concern (it supports HTTP/2 out of the box in iOS9, assuming your server also supports it). So yes, you're okay in terms of deployment.